# Excel VBA web scraping with Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, excel-2010

I wonder if somebody can help me with below code.

I normally use same schema without problem but this time I get an error finding elements. I don't know if the problem comes from web design or (probably) I am typing a wrong code regardin FindElementsBy...

Many thanks in advance.

````
Option Explicit
Private ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub ScrapeEntriesTokyo()

    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
    Dim ResultSections As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim ResultSection As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim Entries As Selenium.WebElement
    
    Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    ch.Start
    ch.Get "https://www.worldathletics.org/competitions/olympic-games/the-xxxii-olympic-games-athletics-7132391/athletes"

    Call ProcessTable
    
End Sub

Sub ProcessTable()
Dim TableToProcess As Selenium.WebElement

    Dim AllRows As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim SingleRow As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim AllRowCells As Selenium.WebElements
    Dim SingleCell As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim OutputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set OutputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    
    Set AllRows = TableToProcess.FindElementsByTag("tr")
    
    For Each SingleRow In AllRows
        
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
        
        Set AllRowCells = SingleRow.FindElementsByTag("td")
        
        If AllRowCells.Count = 0 Then
            Set AllRowCells = SingleRow.FindElementsByTag("th")
        End If
        
        
        For Each SingleCell In AllRowCells
            
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            
            Set TargetCell = OutputSheet.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
            
            TargetCell.Value = SingleCell.Text
            
            
        Next SingleCell
        
        ColNum = 0
        
    Next SingleRow
    
    OutputSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    OutputSheet.ListObjects.Add Source:=OutputSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```
````

Comment: You haven't told us what the errors are, where the errors occur or what the desired table to scrape should be. Looking at the page, and making a somewhat educated guess, I suspect you need to set a longer explicit wait for elements.

Comment: Try executing code line by line with F8, if the longer time allowed leads to error going away then that is the issue and you need to set an explicit rather than implicit wait time.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. The error I got was "Run-time error '91'. Object variable or with block variable not set" and it appeared at line Set AllRows = TableToProcess.FindElementsByTag("tr"). On the other hand, the table I wanted to scrape was" styles_table__oNcJD". I have tried with longer explicit wait but it didn't work. Anyway, I have decided to scrape the entire table as a block (not record by record) and I succesfully did with a shorter code. Not sure how I could paste that new code here...